# In JIRA, how do I select a set of fields to display

Tags: jira

We are setting up a new JIRA project.

When I go into admin mode and select the "Fields" tab, and I see a large list of fields we would like to display.

I can see how to go through the list of fields one by one and show or hide each one. But that will take all day.

Is there any way to see the full set of fields, in such a way that I can select or deselect the ones I want, and then submit them all in one batch operation?

Comment: When someone casts a down vote, it would be nice if they added an explanatory comment

Comment: JIRA has many ways to make fields present or absent (screens, field configurations, field contexts, etc). Please explain, specifically, where you are attempting to do this configuration. (That downvote wasn't mine, BTW.)

Comment: Thanks Scott, I added some more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean that you're going to your project ("http://www.yourjiraserver.com/browse/PROJKEY"), selecting the Administration tab, selecting "Fields" on the LHS, and clicking the pencil icon to edit...this means that you are editing the field configuration.

Field configurations are often shared among many projects. Before you do anything, look at the "shared by xxx projects" that is shown at the top of the field config page on newer versions of JIRA. You wouldn't want to change the fields used in projects other than yours! If you need to edit the field list anyway, you will need to create a new field config for only your project, or else confer with the admins of all of those other projects.

I am not aware of any bulk editing capability for the field config screen, but one easy trick is to use do a control-click on the "Show" or "Hide" links, which will cause the result of the show/hide operation to open in a different tab. If your browser is configured to open new tabs in the background, this means that you can quickly control-click on all of the fields going down the page without having to wait for page reloads.

Do a page refresh when you are done to see the results (or just go to the last-opened tab). This will leave you with a mess of browser tabs to be closed in the end, but those are easy to clean up.

Comment: Cute trick! I also noticed when I create an issue and click on the configuration gear, it shows me the list of all fields, and I can select the missing ones from there. Not sure if that just effects me; I hope it sets the configuration for all users

Comment: Changes made from the toolgear on the issue creation screen will only apply to you. In addition, it only performs a subset-type operation on the fields that were already available: you can choose to further hide fields that are available on the screen/field configuration that applies to your project, but it cannot be used to expose fields that were not previously visible because of the screen config or field config.

Comment: This is the Hundred Tab problem I filed at https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-24961